# MyEclipse Exclude Folder From Project

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I have a gallery folder that is included in a java web project.  The files are quite large so if I have to clean or redeploy the project, it takes quite a bit of time.  I am not using these resources in the current portion of the project.  Is there a way to exclude this folder from deploying to my local server? I am running MyEclipse 2015.

Comment: Are these resources in a folder completely on their own? Is that folder a top-level source folder or a subfolder of one (like `src/main/resources/gallery`)?

Comment: Its a subfolder under root >> projectname/media

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle or something else to build the project? How does Eclipse know that "special" folder is supposed to be included in the deployment?

Comment: I accidentally gave you the wrong path, the folder is under projectname/WebRoot/media so it would be included without special config

Answer (score 1):

You can set an Exclusion Filter on the source folder; that should prevent the excluded content from being in the deployment package.

Open the project Properties and select the **Java Build Path** section. On the Source tab, find the source folder for `WebRoot` and select it. Click the <kbd>Edit...</kbd> button, then you can define an Exclusion pattern that covers your media folder.

Might have to do a clean and redeploy to see the results.

Comment: I was not aware of this and I think it will be very helpful in the future but I don't see a way to add a WebRoot folder, just src folders.  Am I missing something or is this just not possible

Comment: `WebRoot/` isn't already a source folder of your project? Maybe edit the question to include a screen shot of the Build Path and the Deployment Assembly screens of your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I can think of, at the moment, is to move the gallery folder up to the project level, so it will not be deployed as part of web root or as compiled sources or as included projects. To have it deployed, you can then add a new folder under web root and link it to the higher level folder. To set up that link, go to New->Folder (you can specify the same name as the higher level folder, as it is in a different path) then select the Advanced button and the (Linked Folder) option then use a variable, PROJECT_LOC, click the Extend button to select the higher level folder under the project. To not deploy the folder, delete the folder from web root (this will only delete the link, not the linked to folder).